# DI Service with proper cache and dbContext usage

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I really want to make a nice, clean and proper code so I have few basic questions. At start I have a service with `GetName`. `_dbContext` is from other DI service like `_cache`

```
public Task<string> GetName(string title)
{
    var articleList = await _cache.GetOrCreate("CacheKey", entry =>
    {
        entry.SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60 * 60);
        return _dbContext.Articles.ToListAsync;
    });

    var article = articleList.Where(c => c.Title == title).FirstOrDefault()

    if(article == null)
    {
        return "Non exist"
    }

    return article.Name();
}
```

1. In [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro#asynchronous-code) we can read that EF context is not thread safe so I should add `await` after return in `GetOrCreate`?
2. Will it be appropriate to set it as a `Singleton` service and use it in actions and razor views?
3. In [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#recommendations) we can read: *avoid "data holder" objects that only exist to allow access to some other object* in DI services. I am worrying about that line when I see my service.

Answer (score 6):

The fact that EF context is not thread-safe is not related to async\await, so your first question does not make much sense. General best practice anyway is to **not** reuse single EF context for multiple logical operations. In multithreaded applications violation of this rule usually leads to disaster right away. If you use the same EF context from single thread at a time - violation might lead to certain unexpected behavior, especially if you use the same context for many operations for a long time.

In ASP.NET each request has dedicated thread, each request does not last for a long time, and each request usually represents single logical operation. For that reason, EF context is usually registered with scoped lifetime, which means each request has separate context which is disposed when request ends. For most uses this pattern works just fine (though you might still get unexpected behavior if you execute complex logic with many database requests in single http request). I personally still prefer to use new instance of EF context for every operation (so in your example I would have injected EF context *factory* and create new instance inside `GetOrCreate` body, which then immediately dispose). However, this is not a very popular opinion.

So, each request has separate context (if it's registered with scoped lifetime) so you should not (in general, if you don't spawn background threads yourself) bother about multithreaded access to that instance.

Your method though is still incorrect, because what you now save in your cache is not `List<Article>`. You store `Task<List<Acticle>>` instead. With memory cache it works, because storing in memory cache does not involve any serialization. But as soon as you change your cache provider - things will break, because `Task` is obviously not serializable. Instead use `GetOrCreateAsync` (note there is still no reason to add `await` after `return`):

```
var articleList = await _cache.GetOrCreateAsync("CacheKey", entry =>
{
    entry.SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60 * 60);
    return _dbContext.Articles.ToListAsync();
});
```

Note that if item is already present in cache - there will be no async work done, whole operation will be executed completely synchronously (don't let `await` fool you - if you `await` something it does **not** necessary mean there will be some background threads or async operations involved).

It's generally not good to store EF entities directly in cache. It's better to convert them to DTO entities and store those. However, if you store EF entities - at least don't forget to disable lazy-loading and proxy creation for your context.

It will not be appropriate to register such service as singleton because it depends on EF context which has scoped lifetime (by default). Register it with the same lifetime you have for EF context.

As for *avoid "data holder" objects* - I don't see how it's related here. Your service has a logic (get data from cache *or* database) - it does not exists *only* to allow access to some other objects.

Answer (score 2):

> In official docs we can read that EF context is not thread safe so I
>   should add await after return in GetOrCreate?

It's not a matter of EF context not being thread-safe. When you call async methods, you should add `await`

```
public Task<string> GetName(string title)
{
    var articleList = await _cache.GetOrCreateAsync("CacheKey", entry =>
    {
        entry.SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60 * 60);
        return await _dbContext.Articles.ToListAsync();
    });

    var article = await articleList.Where(c => c.Title == title).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    if(article == null)
    {
        return "Non exist"
    }

    return article.Name();
}
```

> Will it be appropriate to set it as a Singleton service and use it in
>   actions and razor views?

I don't think it would be appropriate to set your service as a `Singleton` because your service depends on `_dbContext` which has a Scoped service lifetime. If you register your service as a Singleton, then you should only inject a Singleton (and `_dbContext` is obviously not Singleton... its Scoped). It is probably better to set your service with a Transient service lifetime. Note the warning from the [asp.net core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#registering-your-own-services): *"The main danger to be wary of is resolving a `Scoped` service from a singleton. It's likely in such a case that the service will have incorrect state when processing subsequent requests."*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...

    services.AddTransient<MyService>();

    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(ServiceLifetime.Scoped);

    // ...
}
```

> In official docs we can read: avoid "data holder" objects that only
>   exist to allow access to some other object in DI services. I am
>   worrying about that line when I see my service.

I can understand your worry. When I see `GetName`, I don't see why you can't just get the first article name from a list of articles from within your Controller classes. But then again, this is just a recommendation and shouldn't be taken as a hard rule.

Answer (score 1):

*Some argue that DbContext itself is a repository, but some might argue that DbContext follows Unit of Work pattern.*

For me, I *personally* like to use a small repository which is basically a small wrapper around ***DbContext***. Then I expose ***IDbSet*** from the repository.

*Excuse me for using my sample [GitHub](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin) project, since it is easy to explain in real code than in words.*

**[Repository](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Libraries/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Data/AppDbContext.cs#L10)**

```
public class EfRepository<T> : DbContext, IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;
    private IDbSet<T> _entities;

    public EfRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public virtual IDbSet<T> Entities => _entities ?? (_entities = _context.Set<T>());

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var validationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    sb.AppendLine($"Property: {validationError.PropertyName} Error: {validationError.ErrorMessage}");

            throw new Exception(sb.ToString(), ex);
        }
    }
}

public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
   public AppDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
      : base(nameOrConnectionString) {}

   public new IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseEntity
   {
      return base.Set<TEntity>();
   }
}
```

**[Usage of Repository in Service](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Libraries/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Services/Users/UserService.cs#L16)**

Then I inject the repository to service classes via Constructor Injection.

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
   private readonly IRepository<User> _repository;

   public UserService(IRepository<User> repository)
   {
      _repository = repository;
   }

   public async Task<User> GetUserByUserNameAsync(string userName)
   {
      var query = _repository.Entities
         .Where(x => x.UserName == userName);

   return await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

**[Unit Test Helper](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Tests/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Services.Tests/Users/UserServiceTests.cs#L97)**

It is a little bit tricky to mock async methods for unit testing. In my case, I use *NSubstitute*, so I use the following helper method [NSubstituteHelper](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Tests/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Services.Tests/NSubstituteHelper.cs#L8).

*If you use moq or other unit testing frameworks, you might want to read [Entity Framework Testing with a Mocking Framework (EF6 onwards)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429#async).*

```
public static IDbSet<T> CreateMockDbSet<T>(IQueryable<T> data = null) where T : class
{
    var mockSet = Substitute.For<MockableDbSetWithExtensions<T>, IQueryable<T>, IDbAsyncEnumerable<T>>();
    mockSet.AsNoTracking().Returns(mockSet);
    if (data != null)
    {
        ((IDbAsyncEnumerable<T>)mockSet).GetAsyncEnumerator().Returns(new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<T>(data.GetEnumerator()));
        ((IQueryable<T>)mockSet).Provider.Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<T>(data.Provider));
        ((IQueryable<T>)mockSet).Expression.Returns(data.Expression);
        ((IQueryable<T>)mockSet).ElementType.Returns(data.ElementType);
        ((IQueryable<T>)mockSet).GetEnumerator().Returns(new TestDbEnumerator<T>(data.GetEnumerator()));
    }
    return mockSet;
}
```

**[Unit Test](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Tests/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Services.Tests/Users/UserServiceTests.cs#L96)**

```
// SetUp
var mockSet = NSubstituteHelper.CreateMockDbSet(_users);
var mockRepository = Substitute.For<IRepository<User>>();
mockRepository.Entities.Returns(mockSet);
_userRepository = mockRepository;

[Test]
public async Task GetUserByUserName_ValidUserName_Return1User()
{
    var sut = new UserService(_userRepository);
    var user = await sut.GetUserByUserNameAsync("123456789");
    Assert.AreEqual(_user3, user);
}
```

### Back to Original Question

For retrieving data from cache, I use [this](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Libraries/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Services/Settings/SettingService.cs#L67) approach. We don't normally ***async*** when we retrieve data from memory.

> In official docs we can read that EF context is not thread safe so I
>   should add await after return in GetOrCreate?

***await*** keyword is required for ***async*** *(not because DbContext is not thread safe)*

> Will it be appropriate to set it as a Singleton service and use it in
>   actions and razor views?

It depends on how you use it. However, we should not use singleton service for per-request dependency.

*For example, I use [this singleton object](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web/Infrastructure/Singleton.cs) to store setting and configuration which will never change in application lifetime.*

> In official docs we can read: avoid "data holder" objects that only
>   exist to allow access to some other object in DI services. I am
>   worrying about that line when I see my service.

It is not common to store entire Article tables into cache.

If you store too many data in server memory, server will eventually throw Out of Memory Exception. In some cases, it is even slower than querying a single record from database.

Comment: Shouldn't SaveChangesAsync be throwing a new DbEntityValidationException, rather than a generic exception?

Comment: Good catch. Yes, you can rethrow DbEntityValidationException if you want, but in my case, I have all the required information that I need to fix the DB issue.

Comment: In  `class EfRepository<T>` why are you are injecting DbContext as well as inheriting from it? Inheritence makes no sense, you can simply create a `SaveChangesAsync()` method instead of overriding it. Further where is the use of `AppDbContext `